# How do you make an html element have the same height as the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment I've been using the css `line-height` property in the parent div to increase the line spacing, and this works fine for the text, and even `<input>` elements. The only problem is any custom controls like the JQuery spinner or Chosen will try to fill up this entire line height (as they're set to `display:inline-block`)

Currently it appears like this:

[image]

How do I get these widgets to appear the same height as the text? I mean the default `<input>` elements can, so surely it's possible?

Comment: @Miguel Provide us a Fiddle of the css here only

Answer (score 0):

Find the element class/id and on your own style.css you can customize it's property with **!important** But use of !important is not considered as a good practice. (But if there's issue on one-or-two places, i think that is Ok)

Another way can be, why not making changes on jquery ui  css that you are linked to.